# What is an appropriate academic search engine and ranking system for classics faculty and programs?

Tags: ranking, evaluation

Google Scholar and the [h-index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H-index) are widely used in computer science to evaluate academic programs and faculty. Right now I need to evaluate classics programs. I went to Google Scholar and found that the faculty I was interested in evaluating did not have Google Scholar pages. Also, their articles were generally not indexed by Google.

Is there another system that those in the classics use as an alternative to Google Scholar?

Comment: I haven't seen an academic program being evaluated using Google scholar or h-index. Can you give us examples?

Comment: In some areas, publishing is more often done in books/monographs. But, for any journals in the field you need to find who indexes them. Google scholar is nice and all, but it is not a true citation service. Talk with your local friendly research librarian to get access to a real service.

Comment: Faculty are frequently evaluated using h-index for tenure purposes in Computer Science. Every tenure case I have seen lists the faculty member's h-index.

Comment: @vy32 academic programs != Individual faculty

Comment: @vy32 Would they really use Google Scholar's value for the h-index though? In the physical sciences I would expect Web of Science's value to be used.